# NodeJS scraping .ashx page

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request

I've been trying to scrape an Omnik public page .ashx with node.

An example page with GUI (not mine): https://www.omnikportal.com/AjaxService.ashx?ac=upTerminalMain&psid=202&random=0.5716648780507967

The stats I wish to get in my node files for this page can be found on: https://www.omnikportal.com/AjaxService.ashx?ac=upTerminalMain&psid=202&random=0.5716648780507967

I tought it would be very simple, but every solution I tried (request, request-promise, puppeteer and the use of cheerio) never returns a value that I can use to manipulate into another array/json object.

```
//Web scraping Omnik Portal Public
const request = require('request-promise'); //Ajax Request from other websites
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); //JQuery from node

var siteUrl = "https://www.omnikportal.com/AjaxService.ashx?ac=upTerminalMain&psid=202&random=0.5716648780507967";

request(siteUrl, (error, response, html) => {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(html);
    }
});
```

The page with the GUI is no problem to scrape, but every time I just want to scrape the .ashx page it resolves to empty or the json invalid.

what would be the best way to resolve this?

It's my second little node project as I am still learning.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use some browser automation tool, like [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare),

```
export const scrapWithNightmare = (url: string): Promise<string> => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    nightmare
        .goto(url)
        .evaluate(function () {
            return document.body.innerHTML;
        })
        .end()
        .then((res) => {
            resolve(res)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            return reject(error);
        });
})  
}
```